# In swift, how to create an array with all the numbers corresponding to all the days of a month that are present in the first array?

Tags: arrays, swift, date

I have a dictionary like this:

```
var dictionary : [Date: [[Objects]]]
```

I need to create an array that contains all the date of a specific month of a specific year.
The result will be like this when i specify the year and the month:

but before here are the variables that i havec created:

```
let year: Int = 2020
let month: Int = 5

var array : [Date] =[]
```

the result can be like this:

```
array = [date1, date2, date3, date10, date25, date30] // There is only these days for the fifth month in the dictionary
```

the array will contains only the dates of the fifth month of 2020 in the initial dictionary.

Here is how i have tried but i failed:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter = "MM dd yyyy" // to have the numbers of the month and not strings

func arrayOfdays(month: Int, year: Int) -> [Date] {
    for day in dictionary {
        if month == 5 && year == 2020 {
            let date = "day month year"
            array.append(date)
        }
    }
    return array
}
```

I am very novice, and i know that the approach is good but absolutly not the implementation.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is to filter the dictionary keys. Just get the year and month components and compare them to the desired ones:

```
let yearMonth = DateComponents(year: year, month: month)
let array: [Date] = dictionary.keys.filter {
    Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: $0) == yearMonth
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a much better solution

Comment: @Leo Thank you Leo Dabus effectively, filter is an underestimated solution. it is often a solution that we do not think about.